# Streamlit bug only when accessing it through my phone, not on desktop

Tags: python, web-scraping, web, streamlit

I can successfully run [my Streamlit app](https://junegroceryshopping.streamlit.app/?utm_medium=oembed) on desktop but when I run it on a mobile device I get this error and I don't know why. Here's the stack trace from mobile:

```py
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: This app has encountered an error. The original error message is redacted to prevent data leaks. Full error details have been recorded in the logs (if you're on Streamlit Cloud, click on 'Manage app' in the lower right of your app).

File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/mount/src/recipescraper/streamlit.py", line 263, in <module>
    df_download = create_df(recs, num_people)
File "/mount/src/recipescraper/streamlit.py", line 135, in create_df
    scraper = scrape_me(recipe)
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/recipe_scrapers/__init__.py", line 487, in scrape_me
    return scraper(url_path, **options)
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/recipe_scrapers/_abstract.py", line 40, in _init_
    resp = requests.get(
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 697, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 794, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema(f"No connection adapters were found for {url!r}")
```

[image: app]